# Python 3: Set namespace for dynamic classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, metaprogramming

I am writing a Python (3.6) program to generate classes dynamically from user-provided Yaml files.

The process seems pretty straightforward using `type()`, but I am not able to control the module name of the generated class.

A minimal example:

```
>>> x = type('hey.Ho', (), {})
>>> x
__main__.hey.Ho
```

Moreover (closer to my real-world code):

```
>>> from abc import ABCMeta
>>> class BaseClass(metaclass=ABCMeta):
...    pass

>>> x = type('hey.Ho', (BaseClass,), {})
>>> x
abc.hey.Ho
```

How do I get my new class namespace to be just `hey.Ho`?

Comment: You're using `type` wrong. The first argument should be the class name. "hey.Ho" is not the class name. It should be just "Ho".

Comment: I tried that. In that case, in the second example, the namespace is `abc.Ho`.

Comment: I'm not saying it'll fix all your problems, I'm just saying that the way you're doing it is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to set the class's `__module__` attribute:

```
>>> type('Ho', (), {'__module__': 'hey'})
<class 'hey.Ho'>
```

Comment: Hah. Spot-on. Thanks.